# cancellation meaning of "{" in string with variable f" " python

Tags: python, string

I want to write string to file in python

that write varuables in the string but print this { like string too.

```
    a = 5
    with open('bootstrap_2.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(f'{ boot , {a}')
```

Desired output:

```
   { boot , 5
```

How can I undo the meaning of the first { that it will be normal string?
thanks!

Comment: Double it.  `f"{{foo}}" == "{foo}"`.

Comment: Doubled `{{` and `}}` are rendered as literal braces, similar to how `%%` is a literal `%` when using the `%` operator.